# Select query conditional data with sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ka.* from Kisi.KisiAdres ka where ka.KisiID = '1192' OR ka.KisiID = '3'
```

My above query gives the result:

```
KisiAdresID     KisiID  AdresTurKod Adres               UlkeKod IlKod   IlceKod PostaKodu
    2114        3       ACI         3-Adress-ACI        TUR     01      163     01010
    2115        3       IKA         3-Adress-IKA-1      TUR     01      163     01010
    2117        3       IKA         3-Adress-IKA-2      TUR     01      163     01010
    3117        1192    IKA         1192-Adress-IKA     TUR     38      163     38380
    3118        1192    ACI         1192-Adress-ACI     TUR     38      163     38380
    3119        1192    DAI         1192-Adress-DAI     TUR     38      163     38380
    3120        1192    DAI         1192-Adress-DAI-1   TUR     38      163     38380
```

I have a table as shown in above result.

I want result as shown below.

```
KisiAdresID     KisiID  AdresTurKod Adres     UlkeKod       IlKod   IlceKod PostaKodu
    2117        3       IKA 3-Adress-IKA-2    TUR           01      163     01010
    3120        1192    DAI 1192-Adress-DAI-1 TUR           38      163     38380
```

the above result is as per below given condition:

```
if exists (AdresTurKod=DAI), 
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=DAI AND KisiID=1192)

not exist (AdresTurKod=DAI) and exists (AdresTurKod=IKA),
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=IKA AND KisiID=1192)

not exist (AdresTurKod=DAI) and not exist (AdresTurKod=IKA) 
and exists (AdresTurKod=ACI), 
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=ACI AND KisiID=1192)

or  

if exists (AdresTurKod=DAI), 
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=DAI AND KisiID=3)

not exist (AdresTurKod=DAI) and exists (AdresTurKod=IKA),
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=IKA AND KisiID=3)

not exist (AdresTurKod=DAI) and not exist (AdresTurKod=IKA) 
and exists (AdresTurKod=ACI), 
get row max(KisiAdresID) where AdresTurKod=ACI AND KisiID=3)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We need few days to guess your DBMS first

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't reflect results you want. There is only one 'DAI' in sample data, not 'multiple' (unless 1 is multiple, which needs to be specified). On contrary, there are multiple 'ACI', but your desired results doesn't include it. Moreover, `max(KisiAdresID,where AdresTurKod=IKA)` is `3117`, not `2117`. Impossible to answer without clear description.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wanted to apply a preference to AdresTurKod

```
SELECT *
    ,case AdresTurKod
     when 'DAI' then 0
     when 'IKA' then 1
     when 'ACI' then 2
     End as preference 
FROM
     kisi.kisiAdres
 WHERE
     kisiID in (1192,3)
ORDER BY preference
```